# error :Unable to install module "auth_ldap"

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

i have a problem, i want install module Authentication via LDAP on odoo for implement odoo on windows server(AD), but  i have a error:

> Unable to install module "auth_ldap" because an external dependency is not met: No module named ldap

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the python-ldap Python package with pip for example :

```
pip install python-ldap
```

Comment: i did your steps but i cant install Authentication via LDAP

Comment: You have the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:-

sudo apt install libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev

sudo pip3 install pyldap

hope it will help you..